# R language saving SpatialPixelsDataFrame objects

Tags: r, object, save, geospatial

Excuse me in advance for the basic question

Converting SpatialGridDataFrame objects to SpatialPixelsDataFrame ones may be a time (and computer memory) demanding task, especially when big grids are involved.

I have been unsuccessfully goggleing around the possibility to create the SpatialPixelsDataFrame object once, and save it in such a way I will be able to upload it later as... an SpatialPixelsDataFrame object.

Can anybody tell me how to do that?

Danke schön

perep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save R objects in RDS files:

```
saveRDS(anything, file="anything.rds")
```

and then load it back:

```
anything = readRDS(file="anything.rds")
```

Someone may suggest you use `save()` to an RData file instead:

```
save(anything, file="mything.RData")
```

but that means unless you do a bit of fiddling you will have to load it into a thing called `anything`:

```
rm(anything)
load(file="mything.RData")
summary(anything) # A magic "anything" has appeared!
```

So use RDS files, then you can load them back to any object name you like:

```
foo = readRDS("anything.rds")
bar = readRDS("anything.rds")
```

and so on.